# FIDE rules when opponent accidentally promotes to your Queen

Tags: rules, fide, pawn-promotion, illegal-move

This happened to someone else recently in a time scramble during an OTB game. His opponent promoted a pawn and placed a Queen of the wrong color on the board. He was corrected by the player and the game continued for a bit.

I was wondering what the rules say about this situation.

So if your opponent promotes a pawn to a Queen and accidentally places your Queen on the board instead of his own, can you claim a win because of an illegal move? And if you don't claim, but continue to play on without correcting the situation, is that Queen officially yours?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> So if your opponent promotes a pawn to a Queen and accidentally places
>   your Queen on the board instead of his own, can you claim a win
>   because of an illegal move?

No, you can't. There is no illegal move until the player either presses the clock or makes another move (after the opponent has moved).

Here is what the [FIDE Laws of Chess](https://old.fide.com/fide/handbook.html?id=208&view=article) have to say:

> 3.7.5.1   When a player, having the move, plays a pawn to the rank furthest from its starting position, he must exchange that pawn as
>   part of the same move for a new queen, rook, bishop or knight **of the
>   same colour** on the intended square of arrival.
>
> 3.10.2    A move is illegal when it fails to meet the relevant requirements of Articles 3.1 – 3.9
>
> 6.2.1 During the game each player, having made his move on the chessboard, shall stop his own clock and start his opponent’s clock
>   (that is to say, he shall press his clock). **This “completes” the
>   move.** A move is also completed if:
>
> 6.2.1.1   the move ends the game (see Articles 5.1.1, 5.2.1, 5.2.2, 9.6.1 and 9.6.2), or
>
> 6.2.1.2 the player has made his next move, when his previous move was not completed.
>
> 7.5.1 **An illegal move is completed once the player has pressed his clock**. If during a game it is found that an illegal move has been
>   completed, the position immediately before the irregularity shall be
>   reinstated. If the position immediately before the irregularity cannot
>   be determined, the game shall continue from the last identifiable
>   position prior to the irregularity. Articles 4.3 and 4.7 apply to the
>   move replacing the illegal move. The game shall then continue from
>   this reinstated position.
>
> 7.5.5 After the action taken under Article 7.5.1, 7.5.2, 7.5.3 or 7.5.4 for the first **completed** illegal move by a player, the arbiter shall give two minutes extra time to his opponent; for the
>   second **completed** illegal move by the same player the arbiter shall
>   declare the game lost by this player. However, the game is drawn if
>   the position is such that the opponent cannot checkmate the player’s
>   king by any possible series of legal moves.

So, first of all, yes, promoting to the wrong piece is an illegal move (3.7.5.1 and 3.10.2)

Secondly, just making an illegal move does not attract any penalty (other than having to make a legal move with the piece touched or captured). The move only attracts punishment when it is completed (7.5.1 and 7.5.5) by pressing the clock or making a subsequent move.

Thirdly, you cannot claim a win for the first completed illegal move, only for the second (7.5.5). This rule now also applies to rapid and blitz.

> And if you don't claim, but continue to play on without correcting the
>   situation, is that Queen officially yours?

At standard time controls, no. According to 7.5.1 the position before the illegal move must be reinstated and a legal move made.

However, rapid and blitz are different.

> **Appendix A. Rapid chess**
>
> ...
>
> A.4.2 If the arbiter observes an action taken under Article 7.5.1,
>   7.5.2, 7.5.3 or 7.5.4, he shall act according to Article 7.5.5, provided the opponent has not made his next move. If the arbiter does
>   not intervene, the opponent is entitled to claim, provided the
>   opponent has not made his next move. **If the opponent does not claim
>   and the arbiter does not intervene, the illegal move shall stand and
>   the game shall continue.** Once the opponent has made his next move,
>   an illegal move cannot be corrected unless this is agreed by the
>   players without intervention of the arbiter.
>
> **Appendix B. Blitz**
>
> ...
>
> B.4 Otherwise, play shall be governed by the Rapid chess Laws as in
>   Article A.2 and A.4.

In rapid and blitz the standard rules for punishment only apply if there are conditions which will only occur in very high level tournaments, if then. These are that the moves are recorded independently and there are enough arbiters (one per 3 games at rapid and one per game at blitz) to properly see what is going on. Otherwise article A.4 applies and you can keep your extra queen.

Comment: Moral of the story: If this ever happens in blitz/rapid, immediately blitz out any legal move that doesn't lose either the queen or the game (if possible) - doing so prevents your opponent from retracting the move (assuming they have yet to hit the clock)!

Answer (score 1):

That would be an illegal move, so rule 7.5.1 should apply - when it is found that an illegal move has been completed, the position before that move shall be reinstated.
And yes, you can claim a win due to the illegal move (assuming that in the given situation an illegal move loses - usually when the opponent already made another illegal move before), just as it is also an illegal move to move the pawn to the last rank without replacing it.